# Keyboard Shortcut for Error message tool tip for Red underline in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

This may be silly question but for me it is good to know the keyboard shortcut for viewing the red underline error messages in SSMS.

Normally, if I mouse over, I will know the tool tip message.

Is there any keyboard shortcut for this? Below is an example (click to enlarge): [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The message you're looking for is in a UI tooltip; there's no keyboard shortcut to display tooltips.

IMO, you'd be wise to turn on the `Error List` view (View > Error List, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>). It will show a list of the errors, syntax or otherwise, in an easy to read format.